# Check multiple sets of radio buttons with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I use multiple sets of radio buttons in my form. It looks like this:

```
<input name='project[0]' type='radio' />
<input name='project[0]' type='radio' />
<input name='project[0]' type='radio' />

<input name='project[1]' type='radio' />
<input name='project[1]' type='radio' />
<input name='project[1]' type='radio' />
```

I could use following syntax as well:

```
<input name='project_0' type='radio' />
<input name='project_0' type='radio' />
<input name='project_0' type='radio' />

<input name='project_1' type='radio' />
<input name='project_1' type='radio' />
<input name='project_1' type='radio' />
```

How could I check if every set of buttons is checked using jQuery?

Comment: Use [jQuery validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($('input[type="radio"][name^="project_"]:checked').length === 2) {
   //ok
} else //not ok
```

Where `2` is the number of radio groups starting with `project_` in the `name`.

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/oxogiw/1/edit)

Note that the W3C recommends to always leave a pre-selected option, as users are not able to easily return a radio set to the undetermined (no selection) state. From [HTML4.01 Forms spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.2.1):

> If no radio button in a set sharing the same control name is initially
>   "on", user agent behavior for choosing which control is initially "on"
>   is undefined. **Note.** Since existing implementations handle this
>   case differently, the current specification differs from RFC 1866
>   ([[RFC1866]](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/references.html#ref-RFC1866) section 8.1.2.4), which states:
>
> > At all times, exactly one of the radio buttons in a set is checked. If
> >     none of the  elements of a set of radio buttons specifies
> >     `CHECKED', then the user agent must check the first radio button of
> >     the set initially.
>
> Since user agent behavior differs, authors should ensure that in each
>   set of radio buttons that one is initially "on".

This also reduces the amount of front-end checks required. Though, I don't remember any major browser forcing a radio to be checked and the current [HTML5.1 Forms spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/forms.html#radio-button-state-%28type=radio%29) standardizes the ability to leave all radios initially unchecked:

> ***Note: If none of the radio buttons in a radio button group are checked when they are inserted into the document, then they will all be initially unchecked in the interface, until such time as one of them is checked (either by the user or by script).***

Comment: Thank you sir. In my case, it's necessary for all radio buttons to be checked.

Comment: Yes, I just mentioned the last paragraph as while reading through the HTML5 Input element spec, it says that browsers should automatically select the first radio on page load in case none is selected from a given group, but that is still not the case with any major browser. So it is advised to leave a `checked` one by default to warrant cross-browser behavior in case this is changed.

Comment: Seems like the current [HTML5.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/forms.html#radio-button-state-(type=radio)) dropped that in favor of the old behavior though. Nevertheless, leaving a checked one by default in the markup when applicable still reduces the lines of JS necessary in the front end. `=]`